# Status of Phantomjs onResourceReceived Response Body Work

Tags: javascript, ajax, project, phantomjs, httpresponse

I recently discovered that I cannot read the response body of an ajax request with PhantomJS. Looking into this issue, it appears this has been kicked around for quite some time with no complete resolution. I'm wondering if this capability is not wanted by the PhantomJS project for some reason, possibly resource related.

There are lots of old issues and even an old PR to address this, but it is unclear if this is progressing, stalled, not wanted by the project maintainers, etc...
Issue: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10158
PR: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/11484

Does anyone know the status of this capability in the PhantomJS project?

Comment: I would also like to know the same thing, and asked recently on the mailing list (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phantomjs/96nfSXRJ7_g/U8BSq3lpve8J) with no response. My guess is nothing will happen until at least after PhantomJS 2.0 goes live, as this is not an itch that any of the developers need to scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As a C++ programmer of over 10+ years in my early days, I would happily help out. But it really does feel like the project does not want this feature. That is leading me away from PhantomJS, which bums me out. I really just want a confirm/deny from the project on this so I can make a confident move of any kind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same question, and I discovered that this feature has recently been added to the master branch:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/434d4e0101a540525e8f89a657ea553fb38b040b

As of this writing, you'll need to [compile from source](http://phantomjs.org/build.html) (skip the `git checkout 2.0` step), as this change hasn't made it into the precompiled binaries.

Note that it'll only capture the body when explicitly requested to do so in the `page.captureContent` array.  For example:

```
page.captureContent = ['/interestingpage', '/veryinterestingpage'];
```

Comment: Is this on the documentation?

Comment: Alas, it is not anymore in the current revision of phantomjs-master. :(